# Trading other people's money with mine

Tags: stocks, investing, trading

I have created a computer program that looks at many different stock statistics and informs me of which ones I should buy and when I should sell them. I am trading with about $50k and I am achieving a good return.

I'm aware that this is risky but I know people that would like to dabble in day trading, have the money to lose and wouldn't mind getting in on what I am doing.

I believe that if I had more capital, I could be making much more. My idea is to pool our money together to be able to have more day trading power and be able to make more money overall.  Can anyone suggest some ways that I could make this into a VERY VERY small business on the side?

Comment: Having more money to invest doesn't benefit you unless you are receiving an advisory fee.  If you are receiving one then  you cannot be considered an [investment club](https://www.sec.gov/reportspubs/investor-publications/investorpubsinvclubhtm.html) and you may be subject to regulation by the SEC as well as some states.

Comment: Are you achieving a better return than SPY over the same time frame that you've been running your system. You might have noticed that picking blindfolded since March 2020 has produced some monster returns...

Comment: Sorry, but if you have what you say, then why the heck "very very small"? What is the sense here - you could as well do it proper, professional and then start making SERIOUS money. There are people living from that, and the good ones are making a TON of money - rare as they are. There is ZERO sense in keeping it small.

Comment: This needs a locality for local laws. Pooling funds is generally controlled and requires overhead. Details depend on country.

Answer (score 3):

This gets asked regularly.  By keeping the pool of clients *small*, the main problem is taxes: you'd have to form a company, and keep track no only of everyone's balance, short and long term capital gains (realized and unrealized), dividends, etc, **and inform the IRS every year**.

And taking a slice of their pies as an advisory fee.

Plus needing a cash reserve in case someone -- or all of them!! -- needs to quickly cash out.

Bottom line: a lot of your time would be taken up with bookkeeping.